# Creating A CSV file on ubuntu server using cocotb

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, ubuntu

Here I want to create a csv file on cocotb, but the following code is for Google Colab which is working perfectly.

```
import cocotb
from cocotb.triggers import Timer
import random
import pyuvm
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks')

Now i have generated random numbers and then append them in a list, also generated random op_code.
@cocotb.test()
async def CODE_AA(dut):
 
 listA = []
 listB = []
 listC = []
 ALU_CONTROL = ['00', '01', '10', '11'] #['0', '1', '2', '3']

for i in range(10):
 A = random.randint(0, 1000)
 listA.append(A)
await Timer(20, units = "ns")
print(A)
 
 B = random.randint(0, 1000)
 listB.append(B)
await Timer(20, units = "ns")
print(B)
 
  #C = random.randint(0, 3)
 listC.append(random.choice(ALU_CONTROL))
print(listC)
 
DICT= {'A': listA, 'B': listB, 'C': listC}
dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DICT)
dfA_Transposed = dfA.T
print(dfA)

dfA.to_csv('basic_py.csv')
DICT = {'A': listA, 'B': listB, 'C': listC}
dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DICT) 
print(dfA)
```

I want to make CSV file now on Ubuntu server using cocotb, This code is working perfectly on Google Colab. Kindly guide me with the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to omit importing the google drive lib:

```py
# from google.colab import drive
# drive.mount('/content/drive')
# os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks')

# Change directory to somewhere you have access on the server
os.chdir('~/content/collab_notebooks')
```

Comment: For cocotb we will just be using the command "import csv" and then a csv file will be created.